XLS File Download Issue from Admin Button on Crowdfunding App
My developer has created in our Crowdfunding app an "Admin" function. This enables campaign creators to access the info of investors for their project (email, phone number etc). The function also allows the 'Download' of the File (xls) OR should.
The problem the developer has found is that on some Android devices it works but on others it does not. I for example have Android 14 on my Pixel device. However when i try to access and download the xls File - the button is no responsive - nothing happens.
Before we update the app on the app store i need this issue resolved.
What are the problems and How can this be resolved?
Thank you.
enter image description here
XLS file download issue from MVP.
He has tried on other devices but what we were expecting was that this functionality would be simpe and enable the xls file download to work without issues. I have shared a screen shot to give an idea.
